What to do if only a subset of records entered the Journey due to 'Evaluate new records only' setting in Salesforce Marketing Cloud
I set up a Journey in Salesforce Marketing Cloud with a Data Extension (DE) as the entry source containing 10,000 records. The DE is overwritten daily before the Journey is scheduled to start. I configured the entry source with the following settings:

Evaluate new records only
On the first run, evaluate: Only new records added after journey activation

After activating the Journey, only about 2,000 records entered, which seems to be only the records added after the DE was overwritten on the same day.
Is there any way to bring in the previously existing records (the full 20,000) for the initial Journey run?
What would be the best configuration to ensure that all records in the DE are evaluated for each daily run in such a scenario?
